# Convert Yii1 code to Yii2 (changing language part)

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii, yii2

i have a problem. I have a code where i can i change my site language, it's on Yii1

```
      echo CHtml::ajaxLink('EN', array('/'), array(
        'type' => 'POST',
        'success' => 'js:function(res){window.location.reload();}',
        'data' => array(
          Yii::app()->request->csrfTokenName => Yii::app()->request->csrfToken,
          '_lang' => 'en',
        )
      ), array('class' => 'lang_class'));
```

Please help me to convert it ti Yii2, i dont get it at all.... cause i'm new at it.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well in Yii2 there isn't `ajaxLink` anymore. So you can do it like this:

First set your link:

```
Html::a('Link title', 'javascript:void(0);', ['class' => 'changeLangLink']);
```

After that set js click event to the button and call your ajax.

```
$('.changeLangLink').click(function(e){
      //do you ajax request
      alert('Clicked');
});
```